# Display item's name instead of ID when binding collection to control

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8, mvvm, mvvm-light

I have a colletion of BusRoute objects like

```
public class BusRoute
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int BusStopID { get; set; }
    //... other properties
}
```

and in the same ViewModel I have a collection of BusStops

```
public class BusStop
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public double X {get; set;}
    public double Y {get; set;}
}
```

and I'm binding BusRoutes to LongListSelector, but instead of BusStopID I want to display BusStop's Name property. Additionally, after selecting a BusRoute, I want to load second View and I will need to bind a control to a BusStop Name also. So my first thought was to make BusStop collection static, as I need it from multiple places, but I read that isnt preferable choice. So I'm stuck.

Comment: Item is already its own model, so why have a model if you have an item?

Comment: I simplified the class hierarchy to show a problem, there are different properties in Model as well.

Comment: Expose the Item name as well as the item id?  Expose the Item itself, rather than its id?  There's lots of different ways to do it.

Comment: Yeah, but that involves changing the data structure, which I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Can't help you, as it isn't really clear what is happening here.  You say you have a collection of model objects like {code} but you describe two objects. Huh? And your description of what you want to do is confusing :/ can you create a minimal, compilable example of what you're trying to do and add it to an [edit]?  It'll help you get an answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, I think that now it will be more clear

Comment: Not really.  I'd think that a BusRoute would be a collection of BusStops.  As for clarification, I'd really suggest you create one of these http://www.sscce.org/ which solely deals with what you are attempting to accomplish. I always do this before asking. Nowadays, it usually results in me answering my own question :/

Comment: BusStopID is ID of a last bus stop in BusRoute, I think that model structure isn't that important here. I have an collection of BusRoutes, I'm binding it as ItemsSource of LongListSelector. Every object have an Integer property (BusStopID) which I'm binding as Text property of an TextBlock and the question is: How can I convert that ID to corresponding Name property in collection of BusStops?

Comment: Okay, that's clearer.  Have you thought about using an IValueConverter that can access the list of all bus stops?  It's a bit hacky, but it would work.

Comment: Yeah, thought about it, but I must pass the collection of BusStops to converter class somehow.. otherwise it'll have to load it from the file every time. Do you know how to do that ?

Comment: Lots of different ways.  DependencyInjection is one.  Static references is another...